# Spring Boot application using Matlab webfigures throws error

Tags: matlab-figure, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using Spring Boot MVC Maven application to draw Matlab webfigures. My matlab application returns 4 webfigure objects, that I like to present on my application page. I Used javabuilder to wrap matlab code into Java classes. 
However I receive errors:

> Unable to initialize com.mathworks.mwswing.MJStartup

I was able to make application work in Spring XML, but spring boot do not work for me. Do not know why.

My sources:

UploadingController.java

```
package com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles;

import HRVAS_web_v3.HRVAS_web_v3;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWJavaObjectRef;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFigure;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFigureHtmlGenerator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller
public class UploadingController {
public static final String uploadingdir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/uploadingdir/";

private final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(Model model) {
    File file = new File(uploadingdir);
    model.addAttribute("files", file.listFiles());
    logger.debug("This is a debug message");
    return "home.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadingPost(@RequestParam("uploadingFiles") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, MWException {
    logger.debug("This is a debug 2 message");

    for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
        File file = new File(uploadingdir + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
        uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
    }

            HRVAS_web_v3 hrvas;

            hrvas = new HRVAS_web_v3();

            Object[] result = hrvas.HRVAS_Langer_v3(4);
            MWJavaObjectRef ref;

            ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[0];
            WebFigure obrazek = (WebFigure)ref.get();

            ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[1];
            WebFigure obrazek1 = (WebFigure)ref.get();

            ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[2];
            WebFigure obrazek2 = (WebFigure)ref.get();

            ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[3];
            WebFigure obrazek3 = (WebFigure)ref.get();   

            WebFigureHtmlGenerator webFigures;
            webFigures = new WebFigureHtmlGenerator(request);

            String webFig = webFigures.getFigureEmbedString(obrazek,"obrazek", "session", "300", "300", "");
            String webFig1 = webFigures.getFigureEmbedString(obrazek1,"obrazek1", "session", "300", "300", "");
            String webFig2 = webFigures.getFigureEmbedString(obrazek2,"obrazek2", "session", "300", "300", "");
            String webFig3 = webFigures.getFigureEmbedString(obrazek3,"obrazek3", "session", "300", "300", "");

            model.addAttribute("webFig", webFig);
            model.addAttribute("webFig1", webFig1);
            model.addAttribute("webFig2", webFig2);
            model.addAttribute("webFig3", webFig3);

    model.addAttribute("msg", "hello world");
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

Application.java

```
package com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new File(UploadingController.uploadingdir).mkdirs();
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="http://www.mathworks.com/builderja/webfigures.tld" %>

<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ahoj
        <h1><h:outputText value="Hello World!"/></h1>

    <form name="uploadingForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="POST">
        <p>
            <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="uploadingFiles"  multiple>
            selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>;
            total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload files">
        </p>
    </form>

        <p>

    ${webFig}
    </p>


    </body>
</html>
```

webfigures.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<taglib>
<tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
<shortname>WebFigures</shortname>
<info>MATLAB Builder for Java WebFigures Tag library</info>
<tag>
<name>web-figure</name>
<tagclass>com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.JspWebFigureTag</tagclass>
<!--Body content can have a value of
empty: no body
JSP: body that is evaluated by container, then possibly
processed by the tag
tagdependent: body is only processed by tag; JSP in body is not
evaluated.
-->
<bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
<info>Embeds a live figure frame in an HTML document.</info>
<attribute>
<name>root</name>
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>width</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>height</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>style</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>name</name>
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>scope</name>
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>uploadingfiles-springboot-freemarker</artifactId>
    <name>uploadingfiles-springboot-freemarker</name>
    <description>uploadingfiles-springboot-freemarker</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>        


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a</groupId>
            <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>b</groupId>
            <artifactId>b</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error received:

```
2017-03-15 15:24:55.653  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-15 15:24:55.669  INFO 25864 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-15 15:24:55.670  INFO 25864 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
2017-03-15 15:24:56.365  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-03-15 15:24:56.376  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-15 15:24:56.377  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3447 ms
2017-03-15 15:24:56.978  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-15 15:24:56.986  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 15:24:56.986  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 15:24:56.986  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 15:24:56.987  INFO 25864 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-15 15:24:57.334  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1b0b4509: startup date [Wed Mar 15 15:24:52 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-15 15:24:57.464  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles.UploadingController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-03-15 15:24:57.465  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hellokoding.uploadingfiles.UploadingController.uploadingPost(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile[],org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException,com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException
2017-03-15 15:24:57.468  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-03-15 15:24:57.468  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-03-15 15:24:57.558  INFO 25864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-15 15:24:57.558  INFO 25864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-15 15:24:57.632  INFO 25864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-15 15:24:58.032  INFO 25864 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer         : ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
2017-03-15 15:24:58.282  INFO 25864 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-15 15:24:58.455  INFO 25864 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-15 15:24:58.464  INFO 25864 --- [           main] c.h.uploadingfiles.Application           : Started Application in 6.165 seconds (JVM running for 6.694)
2017-03-15 15:25:07.087  INFO 25864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-15 15:25:07.087  INFO 25864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-15 15:25:07.110  INFO 25864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 22 ms
Unable to initialize com.mathworks.mwswing.MJStartup
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureAxisComponentProxy.chooseGraphicsConfigurationByVisual(FigureAxisComponentProxy.java:239)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureAxisComponentProxy.construct(FigureAxisComponentProxy.java:66)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureAxisComponentProxy.setVisual(FigureAxisComponentProxy.java:112)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigureHG1Mediator.initializeClient(FigureHG1Mediator.java:51)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer.doInitializePeer(FigurePeer.java:407)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.FigurePeer$1.run(FigurePeer.java:353)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$Invoker$5$1.run(AWTUtilities.java:562)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.ThreadContext$1.call(ThreadContext.java:78)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.ThreadContext.callWithContext(ThreadContext.java:107)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.ThreadContext.runWithContext(ThreadContext.java:75)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.context.MvmContext.runWithContext(MvmContext.java:93)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$Invoker$5.runWithOutput(AWTUtilities.java:559)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$Invoker$2.watchedRun(AWTUtilities.java:447)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.AWTUtilities$WatchedRunnable.run(AWTUtilities.java:378)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Wed Mar 15 15:26:12 2017
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding  : Disabled
  Default Encoding: windows-1250
  MATLAB Root     : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80
  MATLAB Version  : 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
  Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7
  Processor ID    : x86 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine : Java 1.7.0_80-b15 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System   : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 000000001a78ae90  RBX = 000000001703d700
  RCX = 000000001a698390  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 000000001798f8e8  RBP = 0000000000000001
  RSI = 0000000018785280  RDI = 000000001a698390

   R8 = 0000000000000001   R9 = 000000001545ff70
  R10 = 00000000154f76f0  R11 = 00003b0307bc0004
  R12 = 000000001a3fffe0  R13 = 0000000017990fd8
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 000000001798fd18

  RIP = 0000000000000000  EFL = 00010246

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x0000000000000000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe+00000000 ???+8791431836623
[  1] 0x0000000011907e73 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwgui.dll+00556659 ( wm_DestroyWindow+000163 )
[  2] 0x00000000138d2381 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+00598913 ( FigureHandleHGPeerQueue+014081 )
[  3] 0x000000001388ceb5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+00315061 ( hgHitTest+003861 )
[  4] 0x0000000013c51512 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+04265234 ( gsDoMexGet+000450 )
[  5] 0x0000000013c516ae C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+04265646 ( gsDoMexGet+000862 )
[  6] 0x0000000013c562ab C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+04285099 ( HO_Delete+000027 )
[  7] 0x0000000013c6da3a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+04381242 ( hgConvertUDInterfaceToHandle+012010 )
[  8] 0x0000000074d2cd13 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\udd.dll+00183571 ( UDInterface::destroyInternals+000067 )
[  9] 0x0000000074d2ce96 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\udd.dll+00183958 ( UDInterface::destroyUnconditional+000230 )
[ 10] 0x0000000074d2cf5b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\udd.dll+00184155 ( UDInterface::destroy+000123 )
[ 11] 0x0000000013c6a7b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+04368305 ( setupHGUDInterface+003713 )
[ 12] 0x0000000013c9703c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+04550716 ( gsPlotFcnSwitch+067372 )
[ 13] 0x000000005f904830 C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\MSVCR90.dll+00477232 ( tanhf+031920 )
[ 14] 0x000000005f8d3b3c C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_08e61857a83bc251\MSVCR90.dll+00277308 ( _is_exception_typeof+000464 )
[ 15] 0x0000000077b1b681                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00308865 ( RtlRestoreContext+000738 )
[ 16] 0x000000001388d426 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+00316454 ( hgHitTest+005254 )
[ 17] 0x000000001388d5a1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hg.dll+00316833 ( hgFigure+000289 )
[ 18] 0x0000000073bc6aea C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\hgbuiltins.dll+00092906 ( MLTerminate_hgbuiltins+087626 )
[ 19] 0x0000000074e8d17f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00053631 ( Mfunction_handle::dispatch+001023 )
[ 20] 0x0000000074e8cf82 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00053122 ( Mfunction_handle::dispatch+000514 )
[ 21] 0x000007fee2b79482 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00496770 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+309314 )
[ 22] 0x000007fee2b75ca4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00482468 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+295012 )
[ 23] 0x000007fee2b5de1f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00384543 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+197087 )
[ 24] 0x000007fee2b5dd80 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00384384 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+196928 )
[ 25] 0x000007fee2b8197d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00530813 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+343357 )
[ 26] 0x000007fee2b80271 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00524913 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+337457 )
[ 27] 0x000007fee2b620e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00401641 ( inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+214185 )
[ 28] 0x0000000074e8c80d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00051213 ( Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+000509 )
[ 29] 0x0000000074e8d0d6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00053462 ( Mfunction_handle::dispatch+000854 )
[ 30] 0x000007fee2b22cd8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00142552 ( MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MExceptionEnvelope+003336 )
[ 31] 0x000007fee2bdbeb2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00900786 ( inMexCallMATLAB+000738 )
[ 32] 0x000007fee2bdbb9e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00899998 ( IInterpreter::GetInterpreterBridge+148286 )
[ 33] 0x000007fee3061d61 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+05643617 ( inCallFcnWithTrapInDesiredWS+000097 )
[ 34] 0x00000000750b33d2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00734162 ( iqm::BaseFEvalPlugin::inCallFcnWithTrap+000066 )
[ 35] 0x00000000750b4f2a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00741162 ( iqm::BaseFEvalPlugin::execute+000314 )
[ 36] 0x0000000074996d22 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00159010 ( mcr_init_std_output+020802 )
[ 37] 0x000000007507a00e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00499726 ( iqm::IqmQE::qeInstance+027422 )
[ 38] 0x0000000075071ff6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00466934 ( iqm::BaseIqmPlugin::createEvent+042774 )
[ 39] 0x000000001451e0b6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00385206 ( UIW_IsUserMessage+000086 )
[ 40] 0x000000001451e7b9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00387001 ( UIW_SetGLIMUserMsg+000153 )
[ 41] 0x00000000779f87b2                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00165810 ( GetMenuBarInfo+000626 )
[ 42] 0x00000000779df587                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00062855 ( SystemParametersInfoW+000247 )
[ 43] 0x00000000779e4815                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00083989 ( IsProcessDPIAware+000453 )
[ 44] 0x0000000077b1bc65                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00310373 ( KiUserCallbackDispatcher+000031 )
[ 45] 0x00000000779e908a                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00102538 ( PeekMessageW+000182 )
[ 46] 0x00000000779e506e                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00086126 ( GetKeyState+000238 )
[ 47] 0x00000000779e3a07                     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll+00080391 ( PeekMessageA+000087 )
[ 48] 0x00000000144f8f4b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00233291 ( UIW_SetCurrentDialog+000731 )
[ 49] 0x000000001451fbe2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00392162 ( ws_FreeSystemFont+000546 )
[ 50] 0x000000001314e6a3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00779939 ( sysq::removeCommitDatabaseUpdatesHook+002131 )
[ 51] 0x000000001314fe18 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00785944 ( sysq::removeCommitDatabaseUpdatesHook+008136 )
[ 52] 0x0000000013151a20 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00793120 ( sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+000240 )
[ 53] 0x0000000013151ae8 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00793320 ( sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+000440 )
[ 54] 0x0000000013151ca3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00793763 ( sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+000883 )
[ 55] 0x0000000013151d76 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+00793974 ( sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+001094 )
[ 56] 0x000000007498837e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00099198 ( mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+036894 )
[ 57] 0x0000000074988665 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00099941 ( mcr::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+037637 )
[ 58] 0x000000007497b166 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v80\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00045414 ( DepfunRules::postWarning+003430 )
[ 59] 0x00000000778c59cd                   C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll+00088525 ( BaseThreadInitThunk+000013 )
[ 60] 0x0000000077afa561                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00173409 ( RtlUserThreadStart+000033 )


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as C:\Users\640398\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.25864-1 **


Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
FatalException
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:36.913s
Finished at: Wed Mar 15 15:26:26 CET 2017
Final Memory: 9M/219M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project uploadingfiles-springboot-freemarker: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: -1073740771 (Exit value: -1073740771) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: It seems calling of matlab generated class cause error. Program throws the same error even after removing the display of webfigure in *.jsp page.  Maybe calling of matlab does not work with embedded Tomcat?

Comment: Please help anybody...

Answer (score 0):

### Exception:

> Unable to initialize com.mathworks.mwswing.MJStartup

### Solution:

[Mathworks support team](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/4622813-mathworks-support-team) has given solution for this error

> Please note that MATLAB is officially supported only for single
>   monitor setups.
>
> You can try to work around this issue by changing the Java Virtual
>   Machine that MATLAB uses. See the related solution below for
>   instructions on how to do this.
>
> To check that MATLAB is using the new JVM, launch MATLAB using the
>   `-nodisplay` option and enter 'version -java' at the MATLAB command
>   prompt.
>
> **If MATLAB is not using the new JVM, you may need to create a symbolic link from MATLAB's Java path** (for example,
>   `/usr/local/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre1.6.0_13`) to the new JVM.
>   Then add a file called
>   `/usr/local/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre.cfg` to contain the single
>   line:
>
> 1.6.0_13

### Resource Link:

1. [Why do I get an "Unable to initialize
   com.mathwo​rks.mwswin​g.MJStartu​p" error when I launch MATLAB 7.8
   (R2009a) on a second display in Linux?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101637-why-do-i-get-an-unable-to-initialize-com-mathworks-mwswing-mjstartup-error-when-i-launch-matlab-7?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)